# Should cc_tests in AOSP be on system or vendor?

Tags: android-source, android-testing, android-soong

What `vendor` settings should I apply to `cc_tests`?  (vendor or system?)

I noticed one of my `cc_test`s relied on `libgcov` which is only available on the system, which suggests to me that maybe tests are a system only thing.  If my poor understanding of what `cc_test` does I'm also confused about what it even means to apply vendor settings to a `cc_test`.

In any case, I have many modules that are `vendor: true`, some of them are libs that the `cc_test`s rely on.  Should my `cc_test`s also be on vendor?  Or should any module that needs to be accessed by a `cc_test` by marked `vendor_available` and keep my `cc_test` on system?

Comment: Looking through the AOSP code, I see examples of tests on both system and vendor, so I think my question is more-or-less invalid.  That said, I do want code coverage reports and will have to find a solution to use `libgcov` with vendor tests (either by defining my own, or something.)